# Dynamic sized bitmaps in rust

Tags: rust, bitmap

I'm trying to store a graph using adjacency matrix with bitmaps. But bitmaps have fixed size in Rust and I want to be able to add/remove new nodes. Is there a dynamic bitmap structure in Rust that I can use for this task?

```
pub struct Graph {
    pub matrix: Vec<Vec<bool>>,  
    pub free_list: Vec<Node>,
}

       A       B      C
   A [[false, false, false],    [[0, 0, 0],
   B  [true, false, false], ->   [1, 0, 0], : A -> B -> C
   C  [true, false, false]]      [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I think this question might be a bit easier to answer if you showed some code with a fixed-sized bitmap and what kind of "node" you're trying to add to it. (Wouldn't a `Vec<u8>` or a `HashSet<…>` do?)

Comment: I edited the question. Indeed yes, I could use Vec<u8> but my goal is to make the adjacency matrix small as possible so I would rather use a dynamic sized bitmap (if such a thing even exists).

Comment: Internally, what you want will always be a `Vec<u8>`, since addressing in modern computers happens at byte level. You could build yourself a wrapper that goes `(bytevec[i / u8::BITS] >> (i % u8::BITS)) & 1` (or maybe use `usize` instead of `u8`, for aligned memory access speed). I think the trickier problem you have is that you need to resize a 2D array. But that's a different question.

Comment: Also, why reinvent the wheel? https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/

Comment: Two notes: 1. a `bool` has the same size as a `u8`, and 2. for both size and speed you should use a single `Vec<_>` rather than a `Vec<Vec<_>>` and address it as `matrix[row*width + column]`.

Comment: @Caesar the reason why I'm not using the petgraph is that I'm writing this contract for solana chain and petgraph graphs can't be serialized with solana serializers.

Comment: @Jmb how can I add new columns and rows with one vector?

Comment: @brknarsy same as for the multiple-vectors solution: allocate a new buffer with the necessary size and copy data from the old buffer (that's what `Vec<Vec<_>>` does under the hood when you resize it). You can avoid reallocating each time by using a stride greater than `width` to allocate a bit of extra space to allow growing into (similar to what `Vec` does with its `capacity`).

Comment: @Jmb thank you for the optimization trick! I wonder if I can apply the same to HashMap<u64, HashSet<u64>>.

Comment: If Solana has learned anything from serde (would be rather sad if it hadn't), there should be some way of implementing a custom serialization method for your data that handles petgraph. Or you could convert  between petgraph and solana-serializable data after/before de/serialization. Really, avoid implementing a graph library.

Comment: There is a way of implementing custom serialization methods, they're not very beginner friendly though, also thank you for the clear explanation. I'll try to serialize petgraph graphs, if somehow I can't, I'll continue with HashMap<u64, HashSet<u64>>